# Having a paper in which the research question is not clear

Tags: publications, research-process, rejection

As a young researcher in economics, I have already published 3 papers in decent journals. Is it sometimes normal to write a paper in which the research question is not clear at all, the motivation is lacking and also you do not understand where the problem in the paper is?

I have heard 2-3 times from various referee reports that my paper lacks motivation and I have already tried hard to handle these issues each time but I cannot see where the problem is. A paper of mine has been rejected several times and now I am questioning my ability to do research.

Comment: I think it's hard to comment without knowing your work - do you have an advisor to ask? Some categories of research without a motivating question are derided as fishing expeditions and can be a big methodological liability for a field. Or, maybe you're just having trouble articulating a question that's already part of your thought process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the focus on research questions is misguided and of little use for publishing in high-level economics journals. You can take a look at papers published in top journals and ask yourself what the research question is. Often, it is unclear or irrelevant. Motivation is a broad and misleading term: Your motivation for doing research is irrelevant, the question is what motivates readers and referees. Why should they care?

Many papers have exactly the same research question: How does education impact earnings? Is there gender discrimination in wages? Under what conditions do Bewley models have recursive equilibria? How are financial shocks transmitted to the real sector?

If you want to get a paper addressing one of these questions published, you should convince referees and readers that you actually answer them in a better way; existing answers are unsatisfactory in some way: Previous econometric studies may not be able to control for some other factors, and your does. Other existence theorems require assumptions that rule out many popular function forms; your theorem does not. And so on. You have to connect your work to the existing literature and to how it falls short.

There is an [excellent talk](https://youtu.be/vtIzMaLkCaM) on writing academic papers by Larry McEnerney, long-term director of the University of Chicago's writing program, that addresses the topic of what motivates people to read papers and I strongly encourage watching it.

Answer (score 11):

Just sort of a distinction, the research question being clear is a different idea from it lacking motivation. If I wanna study the impact of the minimum wage on employment, I could say this up front, but the study could still lack motivation if I don't justify why this particular case study is important or cool to learn about.

Even if the justification is small. Like in a current paper, I write at the end of the intro "The goal of this paper is to compare methods for donor selection with respect
to performance based metrics that SC researchers should care about...We believe these algorithms will be of use to policy analysts and statisticians who use SC more broadly."

Of course the meat of that justification follows from the preceding paragraphs, but either way, I say *why* the paper is worthy of econometricians to take note of. Honestly, I do this all the time. I model my writing style off papers that appear in my favorite econometrics journals (not completely of course), but I do seek to emulate that clear, concise, well stated style that top journals have. So I would read that if I were you, if it helps you write and organize better.

Answer (score 8):

It is easy to understand rejections if your research question isn't clearly stated in the paper. The reader wants to know what to expect as an outcome.

It is easy to understand rejections if your motivation for the (well stated) research question isn't clearly stated in the paper. The reader wants to know why this question is important and what it will contribute to the field.

Perhaps you have just neglected to clearly state things that are actually clear in your head. You may be making assumptions about readers and their knowledge and motivations. You can probably correct that.

But if you are writing papers with no clearly defined research question or reason for asking it - doing unfocused research - then you may have a long way to go.

Expository papers are sometimes useful and may be publishable in some venues, but they aren't really research and are usually based on things known in the field, so don't tend to advance it.

Clarity is valued. Necessary.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it sometimes normal to write a paper in which the research question is not **clear at all** and the motivation lacks?

I'll echo @Bryan-Krause's comment ... *maybe you're just having trouble articulating a question that's already part of your thought process*.

At times, we get stuck in author-block mode. In that mode, we 'see' what we're writing but we are not articulating for the reader. However, in our mind, we believe we are. This is where advisor(s), mentor(s) or four-eye review comes in.

@Jared Greathouse gave a fantastic distinction between RQ and motivation in his [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/195886/162770).

Nonetheless, your RQ and/or objective should be evident even if blurry. I say either or both RQ and objective because in some discipline, the paper can have research objectives only, dropping the RQ!

When writing your manuscripts, you might want to consider templating. Essentially, outline the key areas and ideas/thought and  develop them afterwards. At that stage (writing), you get an opportunity to reflect on your '***why*** the research.

We get around by giving careful thought to

- *why* is research necessary
- *what* the research is about
- *why* is the manuscript written
- *what* is the manuscript saying (to readers/community)

> and also you do not understand where is the problem in the paper?

Philosophically, I'm **critical realism** inclined (though I follow *positivism* or *interpretivism* when seldom need be). Being CR, there's the tendency to **identify** and **describe** iteratively.
Through the understudying process, demi-regularities (or underlying nuances) are brought to the fore. Through **retroduction**, explanatory causal mechanisms relationship are developed.
Unfortunately, you might rejections if reviewers in the journal venues are not exposed to CR or looked at one's manuscript through the lens of the manuscript's methodology.